# Cannot find verticle vertx.web-server-v1.0

Tags: python, module, vert.x

Hello i'm newby in Vertx.
Today i implemented very simple vertx app with python
But it is not working

Here is python code

```
web_server_conf = {
  'port' : 8080,
  'host' : 'localhost'
}

# Start the web server, with the config we defined above
import vertx

vertx.deploy_verticle('vertx.web-server-v1.0', web_server_conf)
```

But i got a error like below

C:\dev\tools\vert.x-1.3.0.final>vertx run app.py
Cannot find verticle vertx.web-server-v1.0

i already installed the module in $VERTX_HOME\mods
and javascript version of the sample is works well,

```
load('vertx.js');

var webServerConf = {  
  port: 8080,
  host: 'localhost'
};

// Start the web server, with the config we defined above

vertx.deployModule('vertx.web-server-v1.0', webServerConf);
```

Could u please kindly mentoring me?

Comment: The example http://vertxio-hornmicro.rhcloud.com/python_web_tutorial.html uses 'web-server' not 'vertx.web-server-v1.0' ... does that help?

Comment: as i know the sample is incorrect.

Comment: module seems installed well. i checked module integrity by using "vertx runmod vertx.web-server-v1.0". It works. I think the problem is coming from python vertx only.

Comment: Are you using vertx 1.3 rather than 2.0.2?

Comment: 1.3. Now i recognize and fixed it. thanx

Answer (score 0):

I used 1.3
I upgraded to 2.1M3.

In internet, there are so many examples which based on old version of vertx and modules.
So it is better to start official page. (vertx.io)
It can reduce confusion.

FYI..

In addition thanx @tim_yates